# Hiding initial zero value in EditText?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been struggling with this problem: I have a couple of EditText(Decimal Number) fields and I have assigned a Double value of zero to them. I can't figure out how to hide the zero before the user touches the field EditText,actually what I mean is I want to make that zero invisible, so the edit text field appears empty when the user looks at the current screen containing these fields.When he touches the text field and enters the zero would be overwritten by the number he entered, and every other text field where the user did not type anything would remain value 0 assigned to it.
My main goal is to make the edit text field appear empty only if there is a 0 assigned to it.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: from where you get your `EditText(DecimalNumber)` spec, as it usually is CharSequence or an int(but thats there to get an R.string)

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `setText("")` on the EditText field, if the number is zero.